# How to combine 2 or more Sqflite queries with logical operators?

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, sqflite

Im currently trying to combine the results of 2 queries in flutter. These are the queries:

```
Future<List> filterExercises({
   List<String> equipmentFilter,
   List<String> muscleFilter,
   int custom, //0 = false, 1 = true
   int recent, //0 = false, 1 = true
   String orderBy,
  }) async {

  Database db = await initDatabase();
  
  final muscleRes = await db.query(
    'exercises',
    where: "targetMuscle IN (${('?' * (muscleFilter.length)).split('').join(', ')})",
    whereArgs: muscleFilter,
  );
  final equipmentRes = await db.query(
    'exercises',
    where: "equipment IN (${('?' * (equipmentFilter.length)).split('').join(', ')})",
    whereArgs: equipmentFilter,
  );

  return finalResult; //need to combine the results with a logical AND somehow
}
```

I know there's the option the use a rawQuery with logical OR / AND, but that doesn't work for my case.
It should be possible for the user to select different attributes and thus filter the list. Im looking for a way to pass arguments to this function and query my table accordingly to the passed arguments but I already fail when merging the first two queries.

**How to add a logical AND to these two queries?**

And furthermore: **How to add even more attributes with a logical AND and order the final result?**

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a way to the first question:

```
List<String> muscleFilter = ['Chest', 'Biceps'];
List<String> equipmentFilter = ['Machine', 'Cable'];

return db.rawQuery('''
    select * from exercises
    where targetMuscle in (${('?' * (muscleFilter.length)).split('').join(', ')})
    and equipment in (${('?' * (equipmentFilter.length)).split('').join(', ')})
  ''',
  muscleFilter + equipmentFilter
);
```

Comment: I ended up using a rawQuerywith very complex String-manipulation for my query with 16 possibilites, since it`s very complex and specific I won`t post it here. Anayway,if there is a more generic or simpler way please write your answer :)